# AutoMapper - How do I map an ID to a Description

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I trust that you are well?

I have a bit of a challenge with AutoMapper.  I have been through a few StackOverflow topics here but I still cannot get my solution to work.

I have the following:

BankDetail Entity:

```
public class BankDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int BankName { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public int AccountType { get; set; }
    }
```

SysBanks Entity:

```
public class SysBanks
    {
        public int Id { get; set }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    }
```

BankDetail DTO:

```
public class BankDetailDto
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int BankName { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public int AccountType { get; set; }
        public string BankFullName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried to use Automapper to map BankDetailDto.BankFullName to SysBanks.BankName.

I have tried a few variations, the closest one (in my opinion) being:

```
CreateMap<BankDetail, BankDetailDto>();
CreateMap<SysBanks, BankDetailDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.BankFullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BankName.Select(dest => dest.Id).ToList()));
```

However I get the following error on the dest.Id:

> error CS1061: 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no
> accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type
> 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?) [C:\Users\jerem\source\repos\EezeBiz
> 4.0\api\API.csproj]

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework, can you add a navigation property from `BankDetail` to `SysBanks`?

Comment: `ForMember(dest => dest.BankFullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BankName))`

Comment: @RichardDeeming Do I need to have a relationship between the tables?  The SysTable is a reference table (e.g Title, Country or Marital Status).  I am not sure if relationships to this reference table is a good idea (I'm still new at development).

Comment: @Jeremiah You would need a navigation property; otherwise, there's no way for AutoMapper to navigate from the `BankDetail` entity to the related `SysBanks` entity. And you'll want to back that up with a foreign-key relationship in the database, to ensure the data is always valid.